# No se ejecutan las aplicaciones de AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

Soy nuevo en esto de Android Studio, las primeras aplicaciones sí se me instalaban bien, pero últimamente no se me instalan. Al crear la App, cuando sólo tiene el texto "Hello World" sí se me instala bien, pero en cuanto hago un par de métodos y un *intent* para ir a otro layout, no me deja instalarla. En el móvil se abre y se cierra sola y en el emulador de Android Studio me dice "nombreApp Has been stoped".

Sé que es algo que hago mal, pero no entiendo cuál, ni dónde está el fallo.

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.x.prueba">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button siguiente;
    Button salir;
    EditText nombre;
    EditText apellido;
    EditText año;

    int añoVerif;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        siguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSiguiente);
        salir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSalir);

        nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNombre);
        apellido = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etApellido);
        año = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAño);

        añoVerif = Integer.parseInt(año.getText().toString());

        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(nombre.toString().isEmpty() || apellido.toString().isEmpty() || año.toString().isEmpty()){
                    Log.e("Vacío", "Error, campos vacíos.");
                    nombre.setHint("Llena todos los campos.");
                    apellido.setHint("Llena todos los campos.");
                    año.setHint("Llena todos los campos.");

                }else {

                    if (añoVerif > 2017 && añoVerif < 1900) {
                        Log.e("Error", "Error en el año introducido");

                    }else{
                        lanzarActividad();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }
    public void lanzarActividad(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Tienes que poner el log para saber en donde está el error, es básico.
Supongo que es porque al crear la nueva actividad no la declaraste en el AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Pon el código. Eso se debe a que está lanzando una excepción no controlada y se detiene la app. El problema no es que no instale, es que al ejecutarse da error.

Comment: Ya he puesto el código del AndroidManifest.

Comment: Publica el codigo que agregaste cuando te comenzo a fallar.

Comment: Ya he publicado el código. Gracias

Comment: Y que te dice tu LogCat ? y como creas una actividad nueva? creas la clase y el xml por separado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estas teniendo es en la siguiente línea:

```
añoVerif = Integer.parseInt(año.getText().toString());
```

Cuando abres tu activity, seguramente el `TextView` no tenga nada escrito, entonces le ordenas convertir el valor vacio `""` a un `int` lo cual no es posible. Además de que no debería ir ahí colocado.
La lógica de la aplicación, debe obtener el valor del año al presionar el botón para realizar las comprobaciones pertinentes. Básicamente el código debería ser así:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button siguiente;
Button salir;
EditText nombre;
EditText apellido;
EditText año;

int añoVerif;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    siguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSiguiente);
    salir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSalir);

    nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNombre);
    apellido = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etApellido);
    año = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAño);

    siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(nombre.toString().isEmpty() || apellido.toString().isEmpty() || año.toString().isEmpty()){
                Log.e("Vacío", "Error, campos vacíos.");
                nombre.setHint("Llena todos los campos.");
                apellido.setHint("Llena todos los campos.");
                año.setHint("Llena todos los campos.");

            }else {
                añoVerif = Integer.parseInt(año.getText().toString());
                if (añoVerif > 2017 && añoVerif < 1900) {
                    Log.e("Error", "Error en el año introducido");

                }else{
                    lanzarActividad();
                }
            }
        }
    });


}
    public void lanzarActividad(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Y si me permites, me tomo la libertad de recomendar no usar caracteres tipo `ñ` o similares ya que no todos los teclados lo tienen, y si alguna vez compartes algún código podría dificultarle la tarea a alguien (imagina respondo el código en chino :P). Pero esto es solo mi opinión.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese era el fallo.